# "unknow provider" when using resolve with UI.Router AngularJs 1.3

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to use Resolve with Router.UI in AngularJs 1.3. But I'm getting error **"Unknown provider: simpleObjProvider <- simpleObj"** error when try to inject the value as parameter in controller. Following is the code from app.js. Here is plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/KR3xzr to regenerate this issue.

```
.state('home.list', {
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'partial-home-list.html',
        resovle: {
                simpleObj: function () {
                    return { value: 'simple!' };
                }
            },
        controller: function($scope, simpleObj) {
            $scope.dogs = ['Bernese', 'Husky', 'Goldendoodle'];
        }
    })
```

Thanks

Comment: You've misspelled the property "resolve".

Answer (score 2):

There is just a typo **resovle** instead of `resolve`:

```
.state('home.list', {
    url: '/list',
    templateUrl: 'partial-home-list.html',
    // wrong
    resovle: {
    // correct 
    resolve: {
            simpleObj: function () {
                return { value: 'simple!' };
            }
        },
    controller: function($scope, simpleObj) {
        $scope.dogs = ['Bernese', 'Husky', 'Goldendoodle'];
    }
})
```

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yQxNNq?p=preview)